# On next event of pretty photo

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto

Hi guys i am trying to capture next event of prettyphoto by this code

```
 $('.pp_next').on('click',function(){
        console.log('next'+Math.random());
        return false;
    });
```

http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#prettyPhoto but it is not working. I guess pretty photo code might have return false or stoppropogation there. any help?

Comment: I guess you could say you didn't account for a large enough margin of error…

Comment: Are you sure that this is the right class? There are also .pp_arrow_next and .pp_arrow_previous for galleries.

Answer (score 0):

depending on how your are using prettyPhoto the div layer to look for is the div layer which holds the main image or video etc.  The javascript replaces the content of this layer in the gallery for example (either automatically via a timer OR by the user clicking prev/next)

Instead of trying to capture the "click", focus specifically on the "change".
(Assuming you want a totally separate method/function to catch this. As there is a built in parameter of the prettyPhoto initialization which does the same thing that can be added when first initializing prettyPhoto called "changepicturecallback: function(){}," which I shall show as "options 2" at the bottom of this answer)

For example on the Gallery implementation, you should see the something similar to the following html div id's within the rendered page (img name and style values will be different):

```
<div id="pp_full_res">
  <img id="fullResImage" src="/image.jpg" 
     style="height: 375px; width: 500px;" />
</div>
```

**Option 1)** For a separate method outside of the prettyPhoto initialization - You can try the onchange event capture on each of these div id's with your console.log or a temporary alert to see which works and then your jQuery method should work.  Something like:

```
$('#fullResImage').on('change',function(){
    console.log('next'+Math.random());
    return false;
});
```

or

```
$('#fullResImage').change(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
  return false;
});
```

Once you've got the onChange identified, then you can attach anything or alter the DOM.

**Option 2)** **Built-In Parameter version use**
The alternative built in parameter which can be added upon initialising is like so:

```
$("#theDivLayerToAttachPrettyPhoto").prettyPhoto({
        animation_speed: 'fast', /* fast/slow/normal */
        slideshow: 5000, /* false OR interval time in ms */
        autoplay_slideshow: false, /* true/false */ 

        /* changepicturecallback Called every time an item is shown/changed */
        changepicturecallback: function(){
           console.log('next'+Math.random()); 
        },
        autoplay: true /* Automatically start videos: True/False */ 
        //etc. other settings for your intialization
});
```